# Is it good to place a paper on a table and keep the laptop over it?Would it cause heat problems?

Tags: laptop, overheating

I want to know whether it is alright to place a laptop over a table laid with paper as its tablecloth?

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly safe.  As long as the paper (or anything) doesnt block the air input or output vents on the laptop.  Additionally, the laptop isnt capable of blowing out air hot enough to damage the paper, or anything else.